# How to simplify the equation $ a\sin x\cos y + b\cos x\sin y = c\sin(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to derive the relation between x and y which are two physical parameters.I am trying to express x in terms of y, a and b. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Ask Wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2x)

it reveals that
$$
\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)
$$
Therefore, 
$$
c \sin(2x) = 2c \sin(x) \cos(x)
$$
So there is at least some solution for $y=x$. But outside of these, you have to do some additional work ...

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in which $x \neq y$ but could be written in terms of $y$?

Comment: I would also try notating $\sin(x) = t$ or $\cos(x) = t$ and the same for $y$. Use that with Pythagoras and you should get a nicer expression.

Comment: Exactly @MathNovice. In above-written form, I can't understand the variation of x with y. In other words, I want an explicit relation between x and y.

Comment: Try dividing both sides by $\cos x \cos y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is of the form

$$p(x)\cos y+q(x)\sin y=r(x),$$ which is a classical linear trigonometric equation.

Let $t:=\cos y$. Then rewrite

$$q^2(1-t^2)=(r-pt)^2$$

which is a quadratic equation in $t$.

Finally
$$\cos y=\frac{a\sin x\,c\sin 2x\pm b\cos x\sqrt{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x-\,c^2\sin^22x}}{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}.$$

---

As shown by @Blue, the converse relation leads to a quartic problem, a little harder, though it has a (slightly monstrous) closed-form solution.

See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be%3D0

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your equation as
$$b \cos x \sin y = \sin x \;( 2 \cos x - a \cos y ) $$
Squaring, we have
$$b^2 \cos^2 x \sin^2 y = \sin^2 x (2 \cos x - a \cos y )^2$$
So, writing $p:= \cos x$ and $q := \cos y$,
$$b^2 p^2 (1-q^2) = (1-p^2) (2p - a q )^2$$
This gives a quartic polynomial in $p$:
$$4 c^2 p^4 - 4 a c p^3 q + ( b^2  - 4 c^2 + a^2 q^2 - b^2 q^2 ) p^2 + 4 a c p q - a^2 q^2  = 0 $$
which does not have nice roots.